# Meaning of KP_Begin and VK_CLEAR names of numpad 5

Tags: ibm-pc, keyboards

The key "5" at the standard keyboard numpad ("keypad" in XFree86) is named `KP_Begin` in XFree86 and `VK_CLEAR` in Windows virtual key space. What are these names originated in? Are they related each to other?

(There are mentions of "Clear" function for e.g. 3270 emulation but this function is by default mapped to Pause, not to numpad 5. Seems not related. The same for Mac Clear key.)

Comment: It's as well used as clear in some SUN Java classes. Also it's only mapped to VK_CLAR when not NUMLOCKed. So essentially what an early _PC_ keyboard (Pre-AT) with dedicated cursor/function and numpad will deliver if the corresponding from the middle cursor/function key.

Comment: Maybe Windows calls it "clear", because there is nothing printed (the key cap is clear) where the direction (up, down, home, ...) would be.

Comment: Adding an explanatory remark to Raffzahn's comment, an example of the relevant keyboard would be an IBM 122-key keyboard, such as that used on the 5250 terminal, which predates the IBM PC. This had five cursor keys in total - the four usual directional keys, plus a middle key located centrally between the four directional keys (just as they are now laid out on the numpad). A variety of keyboards existed in the past, and the Windows VK namespace accomodates many keys found on older IBM technology that have no independent existence on a modern keyboard (for example, the function keys 13-24).

Comment: Clarification about its use in Java. In input-edit routines VK_CLEAR is tied to clearing the field fron all content.

Comment: Raymond Chen speculates (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080211-00/?p=23503, better formatting: http://bytepointer.com/resources/old_new_thing/20080211_046_why_does_ctrl_scrolllock_cancel_dialogs.htm) that VK_CLEAR and some of the other obscure Windows key codes originate from compatibility (planned and existing) with other architectures, such as the NEC PC-98, and other popular keyboard layouts.  (This jives with @Steve's comment.)

Comment: Regarding `KP_Begin`, the only suggestion I have is that on some 3270-type terminals, there is a key between the four cursor keys which is labelled ↖ (see, for example, page 922 of the IBM 3270 Workstation Programming Guide at http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/ibm/pc/3270_PC/SA23-0343-0_3270_Workstation_Program_Programming_Guide_Apr87.pdf ). I don't have enough 3270 knowledge to say if ↖ was, for example, used to move to the beginning of a document or dataset.

Comment: KP_Begin : could it it be for moving the pointer to top-left.  The different fields in a 3270 application is selected using the cursor keys .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`VK_CLEAR` has been present in Windows headers since Windows 1 (it's listed on page 57 of [the Windows 1.03 SDK documentation](http://www.os2museum.com/files/docs/win10sdk/windows-1.03-sdk-prgref-1986.pdf), for example).

Windows 1 could run on, among other computers, the Apricot PC, Xi and Xen. These computers had a dedicated <kbd>Clear</kbd> key, and so it is possible that the `VK_CLEAR` code was created to support the keyboards on these computers. Once Windows supported `VK_CLEAR`, it would be reasonable enough to map an otherwise unmapped key on the PC / XT / AT keyboards to it.

Looking in windows.h (WinUser.H in 32-bit SDKs), `VK_CLEAR` is defined as 0x0C. This is part of a group with `VK_BACK` = 0x08, `VK_TAB` = 0x09 and `VK_RETURN` = 0x0D. That suggests an intended association of `VK_CLEAR` with the ASCII '[form feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed)' character, Ctrl+L, which often clears the screen in terminals and terminal emulators.

Comment: Or to be more clear (SCNR), FormFeed _was_ the clear screen code on glass-tty, the earliest form of CRT based terminals.